# REST API retrieving many subresources efficiently

Tags: rest

Let's assume I have a REST API for a bulletin board with threads and their comments as a subresource, e.g.

```
/threads
/threads/{threadId}/comments
/threads/{threadId}/comments/{commentId}
```

The user can retrieve all threads with `/threads`, but what is an efficient/good way to retrieve all comments?

I know that HAL can embeded subresources directly into a parent resource, but that possibly means sending much data over the network, even if the client does not need the subresource. Also, I guess paging is difficult to implement (let's say one thread contains many hundred posts).

Should there be a different endpoint representing the SQL query `where threadId in (..., ..., ...)`? I'm having a hard time to name this endpoint in the strict *resource* oriented fashion.

Or should I just let the client retrieve each subresource individually? I guess this boils down to the N+1 problem. But maybe it's not so much of a deal, as they client could start to retrieve *all* subresources at once, and the responses should come back simulataneously? I could think of the drawback that this more or less forces the API client to use non-blocking IO (as otherwise the client may need to open 20 threads for a page size of 20 - or even more), which might not be so straight-forward in some frameworks. Also, with HTTP 1.1, only 6 simulatenous requests are allowed per TCP connection, right?

I actually now tend to the last option, with a focus on HTTP 2 and non-blocking IO (or even server push?) - although some more simpler clients may not support this. At least the API would be clean and does not have to be changed just to work around technical difficulties.

Is there any other option I have missed?